# Access images in SD card

Tags: javascript, cordova

```
    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 
    var photoid=window.localStorage.getItem("photoid");
    var photoData=null;
    // Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // PhoneGap is ready to be used!
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;

    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
        alert("Entered sd card");
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
                                    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
                                    sourceType: source });
    }

    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
         console.log(imageData);

        // Get image handle
        var smallImage = document.getElementById('photos');

        // Unhide image elements
        //
        smallImage.style.display = 'block';

        // Show the captured photo
        // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
        //
        smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        alert(imageData);
        photoData = imageData;
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("/sdcard/external_sd/"+photoid+".jpg", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
            alert("write success");
        };
        writer.write(photoData);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert(error.code);
    }


    /*   function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
         console.log(imageURI);
        alert("photo captured");
        uploadPhoto(imageURI);
    } */

    /*  function getPhoto(source) {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
                                    destinationType: destinationType,
                                    sourceType: source });
    } */

    // Called if something bad happens.
    // 
    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
```

I have used the above code to access data in the sd card. But now what i need to do is, get the path of the images present there and put it in a diff object that can access the path and display those images. I have no clue on how to go about that.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: u need the path of the image the user selects, or the paths to all images?

Comment: its not clear what u want to achieve. pls edit and make that a bit clearer. a use case example would be good.

Comment: I need create an object that will contain the path to all the images in the sd card. i.e. I need to be able to access all the sd card images through another object that will have the image path and should be able to open all the images.

Comment: u want to create a gallery or something of all images in the sd card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is write a phonegap plugin for the platform you are developing for. I'll assume it's android.  [Writing android plugins.](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android)
When you call the Phonegap.exec to call the plugin, the plugin, gets the sd card path through

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

and then does a basic search to get all the .jpg and .png files and return a json of all the paths of the files.

Comment: this could be one of the options. But am lookin for right now is Can I get a list of images present in the SD card?? I want the same code to work for android and IOS.

Comment: u'll have to write separate plugins for iphone n android for this job. u can easily get the list of images in the way i described.

Comment: Dont I have any other option to make a separate gallery for the sd card images and display them?

Comment: u can check out the file api of phonegap http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File
u can maybe use this to iterate over the file directories.